# Python multiprocess.pool will fork large memory from parent process

Tags: python, linux, python-multiprocessing

I am using `multiprocess.pool`, and I am also using the parameter `maxtasksperchild`.

Now the problem is, when the `maxtasksperchild` has reached, the process pool will kill the origin child process, and create a new one. But the child process seems to be created by `fork()`, which will duplicate large memory from parent process.

For me, I want parent memory to be a lot ,but I do not want the child process to have much memory(it will even not use the memory), and I also want to use the ability of `multiprocess.pool`.

Could anyone help?

Demo code(this will cost 3.6G memory):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import multiprocessing
import time
from setproctitle import setproctitle

cache_list = []


def init_child_process():
    # set the name of the child process
    setproctitle('child process')


def child_task():
    time.sleep(1)


def test():
    # make large memory for parent process
    # attention, each process will cost 600M, total is 3.6G
    for i in xrange(500000):
        import random
        size = random.randint(10, 20)
        data = {
            u"key_1": u"value_1",
            u"key_2": u"value_2",
            u"key_3": u"value_3",
            u"key_4": u"long_value " * size,
            u"key_5": u"long_value " * size
        }
        doc_list = [data] * 10
        cache_list.append(doc_list)

    # create child process pool
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(5, initializer=init_child_process,
                                initargs=())

    # add tasks, make the pool to spawn the child processes
    for i in xrange(10):
        pool.apply_async(child_task)

    # if you add a breakpoint here(or use pdb)
    # you will find both parent process and child processed have large memory
    # maybe it is due to fork()
    # but I want the child process not fork from parent
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: can you provide a code snippet to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov I have add a demo code, what I want is to create a process pool, without forking parent process's memory, my platform is linux

Comment: Did you read https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods

Comment: @JanneKarila  I am using python2.7, seems that in python2.7, I can not spawn process pool using a context. But if it is python3.4, I can solve my problem